# Sum float with many decimals vs few decimals

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing monthly financial information on our customers in my company - approimately 30.000.000 rows per month, on each row I have a YearMonth ID (int) and a Customer ID (bigint) and a lot of columns with financial metrics (float).
I have a clustered index on (Customer_Id, YearMonth_ID) and a non-clustered index on YearMonth_Id.

If I try to do a sum across yearmonth_id I feel like the query is taking a bit long thou.
Now I realise that my data contains a lot of decimals, e.g. `4.32999992370605` when I import data from my source.

Therefore my question is: Is it faster for the server to calculate a sum with fewer decimals e.g. `4.33` rather than `4.32999992370605`?

Can I expect performance to increase if all my data only contains e.g. 2 decimals? If the performance increases, is it enought to actually feel a difference in speed (seconds increase?)

I have complete control over the data; I am just wondering if it would be worth it for me to erase all financials on my database and start importing it again from the source, cutting away the additional decimal points? The server is for analysis purpose only, so the additional decimalpoints don't add any value for us, so it might as well be cut away, if it will increase speed on the server - but if it wont I would bother deleting everything and importing again (since that will take many hours).

EDIT: I am running SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Not really an answer, but if you say financial data, please consider storing it as Decimal in your database, floats might cause you nightmares. related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750139/precision-nightmare-in-java-and-sql-server

Comment: financial metrics using more than 2 decimals seems a bit odd to me. Most financial transactions are limited to 2 decimals  (sales of GAS in the US being an example when more than 2 are used) but the SALE itself uses only 2 decimals though priced using more.  Using FLOAT with financial transactions is generally not wise.  better to use decimal with a fixed # of precision and scale.  As to the question: do you have an index on YearMONTH_ID? without customer_ID?  if not the group by may be slowing you down.

Comment: If you are not interested in more than 2 decimals, you can use datatype money or smallmoney instead of float. Did you have a look at your executionplan?

Comment: As float is base 2 based I would have thought the number of places in base 10 is largely irrelevant to anything.

Comment: It is not only transactions, but also internal calculations etc., I guess that is why we have a lot of decimalpoints to some of the columns. In my unit we dont care about precision, since everything is on high level - therefore I care more about speed (since we are going to use a BI-tool on top). Will decimal-datatype have greater speed than float; even thou it might take up more space on the server?

Comment: If you want to speed up aggregate queries and this is an analysis server have you considered using a columnstore index?

Comment: Never use float if you are doing any math calculations. You will get wrong results. this is something you urgently need to fix in your structure.

Comment: I haven't been using columnstore indecies before - have just recently heard about them. I lack to understand how columnstore index works in collaboration with a row index - will a rowindex on e.g. customer_id and a columnstore on e.g. Income give me faster results, than say Row-index on customer_id include income ? Did that make sense?
We only update data once a month - so the issue regarding read-only on columnstore I can live with.

Comment: @HLGEM -> I will definitely consider that. We don't do hardcore math thou - we are more concentrating around totals and then customer specific data, such as geo-data and industries and those kinds of split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely the data type is performance related, although one should use decimal instead of float for currency values as indicated in the comments.

Consider adding the columns to be summed as included columns in the YearMonth_Id index. to avoid a table scan or key lookup.

**EDIT**

Including all 40 columns in the nonclustered YearMonth_Id index would increase storage space but allow queries across all customers for a given month to scan data for only that month.

Alternatively, you could change the clustered index to YearMonth_Id and the non-clustered index to CustomerID and YearMonth_Id (without included columns). Queries by CustomerID would require the key lookup but queries for all customers would leverage the clustered index. Like most indexing strategies, there are often trade-offs involved.

You might also consider non-clustered columnstore indexes if you can work within the restrictions (e.g. unfortunately read-only in the SQL 2012 world and requires Enterprise Edition), perhaps with partitioning too (also EE before SQL 2016 SP1.  That would perform most optimally for the large scan.

Comment: I have approximately 40 columns with financials - I guess adding all of them will not be a great idea? How many columns can "safely" be added to the included part?

Comment: I guess that mostly it will be the same, say 10 columns that I will use. Will it make any difference in which order I put them in the included? Sometimes I want Income, other times Expenses, sometimes both - will the same one index be used in each case?

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen, order matters in the index key columns but not the order of included columns; the index will cover queries as long as the columns are part of the key or included.

Comment: Okay - I will try to add my financial-columns to be included in the index then :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you will see much performance increase by reducing the decimal places in your values.

Comment: Okay - how about chaing datatype?

Comment: No, changing datatype will not affect performance significantly, though as others have pointed out, it will improve accuracy.   The best way to improve performance is to look at your execution plan and change your indexes to avoid Scans and Key Lookups as Dan has suggested.